# How do I remove number plate 'sprung' screws from Toyota Camry 1994

Tags: toyota, camry

Screws on my Toyta Camry (UK model) plates are plastic headed and appear to be 'sprung'.  That is when I try to unscrew with screwdriver they turn so far then resist, springing back when I release screwdriver. Both front and rear plates are the original plates and have same fitting.

Never came across this type of fitting before. Should I just force the screws?  Do these bolts need to be tackled from rear?

Answer (score 1):

If they are the plastic screws I am familiar with (black or white or yellow) then they usually have plastic nuts to match.

Well, if they don't want to come undone, make sure you have sufficient replacements then go for it - either they come undone or break.

Just get to the back of the screws first - probably means removing some interior trim.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Thought this was going to be a simple job :/  Have regular screws and caps that came with plates. Just wondering what I will have left to screw into.